# ElastAlert no hits

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

The following are my config.yaml and frequency.yaml

> **config.yaml**
>
> rules_folder: rules_folder
>
> run_every:
>     seconds: 15
>
> buffer_time:
>     minutes: 1
>
> es_host: localhost
>
> es_port: 9200
>
> writeback_index: elastalert_status
>
> alert_time_limit:
>     days: 2
>
> **frequency.yaml**
>
> es_host: localhost
>
> es_port: 9200
>
> name: Error rule
>
> type: any
>
> index: logstash-*
>
> num_events: 5
>
> timeframe:
>     hours: 4
>
> timestamp_field: "@timestamp"
>
> filter:
>
> - term:
>     log: "ERROR"
>     alert:
> - "email"
>
> email:
>   - "my@email.com"

I am getting no hits

> INFO:elastalert:Queried rule Error rule from 2016-09-02 09:33 MDT to 2016-09-02 09:34 MDT: 0 / 0 hits
>
> INFO:elastalert:Ran Error rule from 2016-09-02 09:33 MDT to 2016-09-02 09:34 MDT: 0 query hits, 0 matches, 0 alerts sent

Output of **elastalert-test-rule rules_folder/frequency.yaml**

> INFO:elastalert:Queried rule Error rule from 2016-09-02 09:47 MDT to 2016-09-02 10:32 MDT: 0 / 0 hits
>
> Would have written the following documents to elastalert_status:
>
> elastalert_status - {'hits': 0, 'matches': 0, '@timestamp': 
>   datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 2, 16, 32, 32, 200330, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'rule_name': 
>   'Error rule', 'starttime': datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 1, 16, 32, 32, 123856, 
>   tzinfo=tzutc()), 'endtime': datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 2, 16, 32, 32, 123856, 
>   tzinfo=tzutc()), 'time_taken': 0.07315492630004883}

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was able to resolve the issue by changing the index from index: logstash-* to index: filebeat-* since I was using it to index. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

In output log, you can find that 2016-09-02 09:33 MDT to 2016-09-02 09:34 MDT: 0 / 0 hits, only 1 minutes in query.

Try to setting your buffer_time more than 4 hours (buffer_time > timeframe)
your can reference https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/668, by Qmando reply